# Vuex mapActions, mapGetters, etc... Mixing namespaced and non-namespace actions/getters/mutations/state in the same call?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm just curious if there's a way to mix namespaced and non-namespaced actions when you call, for example, `...mapActions`. I only have one module that is large enough to warrant full module encapsulation and thus namespacing, so some actions would be `things/someAction` and some would just be `someOtherAction`. I am currently mapping like so:

```
...mapActions('nsACtions', ['nsOne', 'nsTwo']),
...mapActions('nonNsActionOne', 'nonNsActionTwo')
```

but would much prefer to combine all into one `mapActions`. Something like:

```
...mapActions('nsACtions', 
    ['nsOne', 'nsTwo'],
    'nonNsActionOne', 
    'nonNsActionTwo')
```

OR

```
...mapActions('nsACtions', 
    ['nsOne', 'nsTwo'],
    ['nonNsActionOne', 
    'nonNsActionTwo'])
```

Neither of these examples work, so I'm curious if anyone has solved this little conundrum. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Nevermind. Figured it out like so:

```
...mapActions({
  nsOne: 'namespaced/nsOne',
  nsTwo: 'namespace/nsTwo',
  nonNsOne: 'nonNsOne', 
  nonNsTwo: 'nonNsTwo'
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I've added this answer even though Matt Larson has found himself a solution which largely reflects the same thing. You can have multiple mapActions on your computed values to separate the namespaces for possible greater clarity

```
computed: {
     mapActions('namespace', ['nsOne','nsTwo']),
     mapActions(['nonNsOne','nonNsTwo']),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case whenever I do the CRUD, I also create the states, actions, getters with default names and put a prefix to reuse the code, if I need to copy it, create a crud screen, everything is ready and I just change it. So, the names of the Actions and Getters are the same, I need to do it that way here.

```
methods: {
...mapActions('especialidades', ['actGetList', 'actInsert', 'actUpdate']),
...mapActions('profissionais', { profActionList: 'actGetList' }),
...mapActions('convenios', { convActionList: 'actGetList' }),
...mapActions('especialidades', { especActionList: 'actGetList' }),
```